# SQL Query in php not working as required

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a Database with column name `DT`, that has values:

```
  1. 16-05-2015
  2. 16-05-2015
  3. 30-06-2015
  4. 30-06-2015
```

`Sql` query in php that I am using is:

```
    $sql = "Select * from logs WHERE (DT<= '$to') AND (DT>= '$from')  ";
```

I have also used query:

```
     $sql = "Select * from logs WHERE (DT BETWEEN '$to' AND '$from')  ";
```

Both the queries are not functioning in the same way as required.

If `$to=31-05-2015` and $ from = any date before 31st, the query displays the `30-06-2015` date as well, but it is not in the range.

When `$to=30-05-2015`, correct results are displayed but choosing any date after `30-05-2015` does not display the correct range, what could be the reason of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, `DT` is not configured as `date` in your DB.

And thus the values are ordered [lexigoraphically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), as strings.

(In lexigoraphical order: `30-...` is before `31-...`, no matter what `...` might be)

You can either change your data to be saved as `yyyy-mm-dd` strings.

Or configure the column correctly as date

Comment: But Format of date is yyyy-mm-dd which I don't want as further I  have to write the date's values in the excel file and excel writes this format as ####, excel only writes dd-mm-yyyy correctly

Comment: You need to separate the two concepts, the way you **store** you're data should not be the same as the way you **display** your data

Comment: My php code is taking values from database in a loop and then storing in excel file one by one, I don't know how to change one specific column's data format there

Comment: You can change the display format with `date("d-m-Y", strtotime($r['DT']));` as @Susain suggested, or other string-manipulation techniques.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your date format to yyyy-mm-dd while saving it to the database and change it to the dd-mm-yyyy while displaying, and also change the datatype of the column to the datetime to make you query work

```
$newdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($yourdate));
```